# Polymer starter kit, Application Error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, firebase, polymer-starter-kit

I'm just building a starter app with polymer starter toolkit.

Everything was fine till yesterday. I could build android app with cordova and run it straight to my android device. Now I've added a new route in routing.html called login where I did setup a simple firebase connection as well.

```js
<script src="../../bower_components/page/page.js"></script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

    // We use Page.js for routing. This is a Micro
    // client-side router inspired by the Express router
    // More info: https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/
    page('/', function () {
      app.route = 'home';
    });

    page('/users', function () {
      app.route = 'users';
    });

    page('/users/:name', function (data) {
      app.route = 'user-info';
      app.params = data.params;
    });

    page('/contact', function () {
      app.route = 'contact';
    });

    page('/login', function () {
      app.route = 'login';
    });

    // add #! before urls
    page({
      hashbang: true
    });

  });
</script>
```

If I run it local in chrome it work really well. But then when built with cordova and I click on the menu to open a page that error appear:

[image: Image 1:menu]

[image: Application error]

Anything to do with the new route or the firebase connection?

Answer (score 0):

@Dragod83
It has to do with polymer being new and not support by many browser.

Polymer - [Browser Compatibility](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/resources/compatibility.html)

In it you will see that Android is support, but they fail to give a version. We can assume it is the latest - using Lolipop or better. Even so, the library that is used for Phonegap development is not that current.

It might working with [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/), but I have not information on that either way.

In short, polymer is not ready for prime-time, and therefore not ready for use with Cordova or Phonegap. This may change, but polymer has been slow in giving details for using polymer on hybrid platforms.

Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

Solved. For some reason (unknown to me) I had to create a folder named android_asset inside

```
AndroidStudioProject/myappname/app/src/main/android_asset
```

Then I paste the content of www folder and it's now working.

Also replaced jQuery & firebase CDN link with bower. Look like file that require a connection do not work.

https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/issues/374